# Some expectation values for a Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, gamma-function, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation

Assuming I have a Gamma distributed random Variable $x \sim Gamma( \alpha, \beta )$. Now I like to have the following two expectation values (integrals):

1. $E \left[ x \ln x \right]$
2. $E \left[ \ln \Gamma \left( x \right) \right]$
   with $\Gamma \left( x \right)$ being the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Many thanks in advance

Comment: At least at first glance, the second integral seems quite complicated, considering the expressions for the Log Gamma Function (see, for example, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html).

Answer (score 2):

First integral. $X$ has density function 
$$
f(x;\alpha ,\beta ) = \frac{{\beta ^\alpha  }}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}x^{\alpha  - 1} e^{ - \beta x},\;\; x > 0, 
$$
with $\alpha,\beta > 0$ fixed.
It follows readily from
$$
\Gamma '(\alpha ) = \int_0^\infty  {x^{\alpha  - 1} e^{ - x} \ln x\,{\rm d}x} 
$$
and
$$
\Gamma '(\alpha ) = \Gamma (\alpha )\psi _0 (\alpha ),
$$
where $\psi_0$ is the  digamma function,
that 
$$
{\rm E}[X\ln X] = \frac{{\beta ^\alpha  }}{{\Gamma (\alpha )}}\int_0^\infty  {(x\ln x)x^{\alpha  - 1} e^{ - \beta x} dx} = \frac{\alpha }{\beta }[\psi_0 (\alpha  + 1) - \ln \beta ].
$$

**EDIT**: Elaborating (in response to the OP's request).

First, you can find [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) the above formulas for $\Gamma'(\alpha)$. Now, using a change of variable, we have
$$
\Gamma'(\alpha+1) = \int_0^\infty  {\beta ^{\alpha+1}  x^{\alpha} e^{ - \beta x} \ln (\beta x)\,{\rm d}x} =  \ln \beta \int_0^\infty  {\beta ^{\alpha+1} x^{\alpha} e^{ - \beta x} \,{\rm d}x}  +  \int_0^\infty  { \beta ^{\alpha+1} x^{\alpha} e^{ - \beta x} \ln x\,{\rm d}x}. 
$$
The first integral on the right-hand side is equal to $\Gamma(\alpha+1)\ln \beta$, and the second integral to $\Gamma(\alpha)\beta {\rm E}[X\ln X]$. It thus follows that
$$
\Gamma (\alpha  + 1)\psi _0 (\alpha  + 1) = \Gamma (\alpha  + 1)\ln \beta  + \Gamma (\alpha )\beta {\rm E}[X\ln X].
$$
Finally, by $\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\alpha \Gamma(\alpha)$, we get
$$
{\rm E}[X\ln X] = \frac{\alpha }{\beta }[\psi_0 (\alpha  + 1) - \ln \beta ].
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Can you give a hint, how you came to you solution? For me this is not clear...
Do you have an idea about the other integral?

Answer (score 0):

1.
E(XlnX)=(formula of expectation, group x) =E(lnY) with Y~[gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution)(alpha+1,beta)

E(lnY)=ψ(alpha+1)-ln(beta) where ψ(k) is the [digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) function.

Comment: wow. Really? Statistical manipulations are so inscrutable. How do you go about figuring out those answers?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. 
But it looks like you are wrong. I sampled gamma distributed data and compared your answer, the answer of Shai Covo and the sampled expectation value. Your formula is quite far away from the sampled. However the one of Shai Covo is very close.

Comment: yep, i was wrong, i forget to include de alpha/beta factor.